# how to login facebook api ver 1.0 using fb sdk 3.14.1?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

It seems that using the fb sdk 3.14.1, users will automatically login to facebook API ver 2.0, even if my app was created before April 30th. Is there a way to force login to API ver 1.0 using 3.14.1, just like `[FBRequest overrideVersionPartWith:@"v1.0"]`? thanks!

Comment: did the solution from bellew work for you?

Comment: @EugeneMi yes, it worked before I switched to v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into this too and found this:

```
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:true];
```

You can then go through the standard v1.0 login procedure. But be warned, while this is turned on, it will disable some parts of the 3.14 SDK that require API v2.0 features.

You can turn it off with this:

```
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:false];
```

See the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSettings/#enablePlatformCompatibility%3a) and the [Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading) for some more details from FB.